# Create dynamic WCF service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I've got stuck with creating a dynamic WCF service to update an old service created manually by XMLWriter, I want to bring the whole solution to standard WCF.

I've found a solution on [ingebrigtsen.info](http://www.ingebrigtsen.info/2008/02/01/programatically-creating-a-wcf-contract-and-exposing-it-part1/) to create a dynamic service but problem is the old service have methods that return result as array of records, but in this solution I have to define a constant type as return type, I can't even create a static record type, because there is many runtime generated methods that have different set of properties.

```
<soap:Body>
<getcdrResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <getcdrResult>
    <_SID>16111250</_SID>
    <Destination>9392191436</Destination>
    <callTime>0</callTime>
    <pulse>19</pulse>
    <Duration>19</Duration>
    <price>0</price>
    <Name>test</Name>
  </getcdrResult>
  <getcdrResult>
   .....
```

I think there's a way to write an inspector on output, but I don't know if it's the answer.

My question is: What is the best answer to have a dynamic ResultSet as return in dynamically created WCF method?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the service interface is "dynamic". That is to say, a method may be part of the exposed interface but then again, it may not be. Is that what you are saying? Please give more information.

Comment: Actually the service loads a list of available stored procedures in database and exposes a public service and then after calling the service it will call related stored procedure in database, and then service must return DataSet returned from SP.

Comment: The service must have a contract, so you cannot use a "dynamic" interface, your methods should have a known return. You could return something "generic" like objeto or string, but reading your comment, as you want to return data, may wcf data services can help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc668792(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching about a week I've found a solution to implement what I wanted.

I wrote an article on [Create dynamic WCF service in C#](http://alikherad.com/create-dynamic-wcf-service-in-csharp/) it's not a complete answer but it solved my problem.

Hope you enjoy

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)